# How can I filter() a value between several columns of my JSON? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, filter

I am faced with a problem and I don't understand how I can solve it.

I have a service where I return the following JSON:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "data": 179,
            "data_form": "Finished - Form Covid-19 Test 1",
            "form": 144,
            "user": 1,
            "status": "Finished"
        },
        {
            "data": 176,
            "data_form": "In process - Form Covid-19 Test 2",
            "form": 144,
            "user": 1,
            "status": "Finished"
        },
        {
            "data": 177,
            "data_form": "Finished - Form Covid-19 Test 3",
            "form": 144,
            "user": 1,
            "status": "In process"
        },
        {
            "data": 178,
            "data_form": "Finished - Form Covid-19 Test 4",
            "form": 144,
            "user": 1,
            "status": "In process"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using a PIPE where I am sending it my array, the value I want to filter and the column where that value is:

```js
<ion-list
  *ngFor="let form of forms | filter: searchValue: ['status','data_form','data']">
  <app-form-user [form]="form">
  </app-form-user>
</ion-list>
```

It works if I indicate the column:

```js
    return array.filter( 
      //It works
      item=> item[column[0]].toLowerCase().includes( text ) 
    );
```

The idea is to look for the value in all the columns that you indicate to the pipe, I tried the following:

1.

```js
    return array.filter( 
      item=> item[column.forEach((data) => found = data )].toLowerCase().includes( text );
    );
```

2. 

```js
    return array.filter( 
      item=>Object.keys(column).every(key =>
        item[key] == column[key]
      )
    );
```

3. 

```js
    return array.filter( 
      item=> column.forEach((data) => item[data].toLowerCase().includes( text ))
    );
```

I hope you can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Works without needing the pass the column, searches all the available columns.**

**One line code**

This filter goes thru each key that you have to check values and return the result.

Detailed explanation:

```
1) Base is the object you posted and assuming you want to filter the "data"
2) First filter goes thru all the elements in the array
3) second filter goes thru all the keys in the object which is element in the array
4) Checking if the column has the data 
5) returns the array of elements if matched
```

```
const text = 'Test 2';
return array.filter(v=> Object.keys(v).filter(key=> v[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(text.toString().toLowerCase())).length > 0)
```

And result is:

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi AdamTheFirst,

Something strange happens when I use .toString() the array disappears and is empty and if I remove .toString() the array comes out in the 
console.log.

console.log(Object.keys(array).filter(key=> console.log(array[key].toString())))

This is what I put
    return array.filter( 
      item=> Object.keys(item).filter(key=> item[key].toString().includes(text)).length > 0
    );

Comment: Hi, @EdissonGabrielLópez, in most cases you need to keep the .ToString() so if the column value is not string it will not give error on the .includes() if result is empty it means "filter" doesnt match with anything 

make sure you are passing the "data" shown in your example given that the while array is not actually array but its an object. please check the "text" you are passing if it exists in the array you are searching

Comment: @EdissonGabrielLópez, I added few more validations. Pls check the updated code

Comment: Works with the latest modification, thanks @AdamTheFirst

Comment: Glad to know @EdissonGabrielLópez

Answer (score 0):

I will use .map() to go through each key of each item, and decide does it found the specific values or not, and return it on filter level

```
return array.filter(item => {
    let found = false;

    Object.keys(item).map(x => {
        found = found || item[x].toLowerCase().includes( text );
    });

    return found;
});
```

Comment: The question is, getting the result without passing the column. Make sure to read the whole question :)

Comment: Hi Tony, 
I don't understand why it returns this error. I got it when I used a forEach()
ERROR TypeError: item[x].toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: Hello Edisson, depends on where did you applied the forEach(), guess the response caused your item[x] becomes undefined, you have to console log the item & x to see if the result is correct

Comment: Hi @Tony Fork
Based on yours and a part of the dear AdamTheFirst and I'm already learning how to do it, what I did was change Object.keys() for Object.values() and converting to string. it looks like this found = found || item[x].toString().toLowerCase().includes( text.toString().toLowerCase());

Thank you Tony